# Express.js : Can't set a correct format of data in json file

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have a json file with data, which I should load to array in the following format:

```
var jobs = [
  { ID: 'grt34hggdggf', Employer: 'A1', Title: 'tobi1', Location: 'Los Angeles, CA', Department: 'department', OpeningDate: '2012-12-26T01:29Z', ClosingDate: '2013-04-26T01:29Z', MinSalary: '30000', MaxSalary: '60000', Description: 'bla-gghrf-bla' },
  { ID: 'grt34hgwerwgf', Employer: 'A2', Title: 'tobi2', Location: 'Los Angeles, CA', Department: 'department', OpeningDate: '2012-12-26T01:29Z', ClosingDate: '2013-04-26T01:29Z', MinSalary: '30000', MaxSalary: '60000', Description: 'bla-gghrf-bla' }
];
```

so, this format is right for me and works with views.
Which format should have my json file. I try the following:

```
{
    "jobs":[
  { "ID": "grt34hggdggf", "Employer": "A1", "Title": "tobi1", "Location": "Los Angeles, CA", "Department": "department", "OpeningDate": "2012-12-26T01:29Z", "ClosingDate": "2013-04-26T01:29Z", "MinSalary": "30000", "MaxSalary": "60000", "Description": "bla-gghrf-bla" },
  { "ID": "grt34hggdggf", "Employer": "A2", "Title": "tobi1", "Location": "Los Angeles, CA", "Department": "department", "OpeningDate": "2012-12-26T01:29Z", "ClosingDate": "2013-04-26T01:29Z", "MinSalary": "30000", "MaxSalary": "60000", "Description": "bla-gghrf-bla" }

  ]
}
```

but when I try to do "forEach" in view I get an error:

```
TypeError: F:\tmp\express-master\examples\ejs\views\result.html:5
    3| 
    4| <table>
 >> 5|   <% jobs.forEach(function(job){ %>
    6|     <tr>
    7|         <td>
    8|             <a href="/job/<%= job.ID %>"><%= job.Title %></a>

Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'
```

so, seems, json file has another format than expected. How to do it correctly?

Comment: Is this happen in Node.js code or you are using anything else, try my answer if you are using nodejs

Comment: as you can see, in html file. But no matter

Answer (score 0):

I found correct format in my case:

```
[
  { "ID": "grt34hggdggf", "Employer": "A1", "Title": "tobi1", "Location": "Los Angeles, CA", "Department": "department", "OpeningDate": "2012-12-26T01:29Z", "ClosingDate": "2013-04-26T01:29Z", "MinSalary": "30000", "MaxSalary": "60000", "Description": "bla-gghrf-bla" },
  { "ID": "fgert", "Employer": "A2", "Title": "tobi2", "Location": "Los Angeles, CA", "Department": "department", "OpeningDate": "2012-12-26T01:29Z", "ClosingDate": "2013-04-26T01:29Z", "MinSalary": "30000", "MaxSalary": "60000", "Description": "bla11-ggh777rf-bla" }
]
```